# Tutorial about TMemIni

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ini

I have used `TIniFile` for saving application data. Now I want to try `TMemIniFile`.

Where can I found good tutorials about them?

Comment: Maybe "Don't use it" is the tutorial. :-) See the comments below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know how to use `TIniFile`, then there's nothing much more to learn about `TMemIniFile`. Use it in exactly the same way.

The only difference you need to be aware of is that any modifications you make are cached in the memory and not written to the file immediately. When you are ready to write them to the file just call [`UpdateFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IniFiles.TMemIniFile.UpdateFile).

That really is all there is to know!

Comment: And that TMemIni can use a bit more memory, but can be a bit faster if you re-read items repeatedly. If you are using small INI files, and/or you only read them once, there is almost no benefit to TMemInifile.     I find TMemIniFile useful when I need to do some wonky thing like "walk through all the items in the file" and scan them (say, search all items, and do  a partial text match for example).

Comment: @Warren `TIniFile` sometimes fails on network drives. In fact it's full of weirdness. After too many bad experiences I have vowed never to use it again.

Comment: I've never seen it fail on network drives, but I have my own list of gripes, and I think that the next time I depend on INI files, I will write my own class, that maintains section ordering the way I like, etc etc.

Comment: @Warren The next time I want to use an ini file I think I'll use a YAML file instead!!

Comment: Also, there are bugs/limitations with TIniFile. Don't try to read a string larger than 2047 bytes with TIniFile. It will be truncated.

Comment: @WarrenP If I were to write my own class for data in files, I would build it off of a TStringList, using LoadFromFile and SaveToFile and my own parsing mechanisms. This of course would be stored in memory, and would require load/save, similar to the TMemIniFile. It's also worth it to try to use just a straight File. I did that once to save/load images, I even started experimenting with using it to play videos/animations. The important point however is that you're better off using something other than ini files if performance is an issue.